# How to convert rpc/literal wsdl to document/literal automatically

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui, wsdl2java, wsdl4j

Is there some tool available or code or library to convert rpc/literal wsdl to document/literal style

Answer (score 0):

you can combine your soapui with apache axis v1 and v2 to work with the RPC WSDL service. I used axis v1 to generate java code from the RPC WSDL service easily.